# How to add a null character to the end of a string?

Tags: c++, c

I start of with a

```
memcpy(g->db_cmd,l->db.param_value.val,l->db.param_value.len);
```

which contains the value "function" however I want a null character to be appended like "function'\0'" I've tried a

```
memcpy(&g->db_cmd[l->db.param_value.len],0,1);
```

This crashes the program. I've tried memset also

```
 memset(&g->db_cmd[l->db.param_value.len],0,1);
```

This doesnt work. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

```
g->db_cmd[l->db.param_value.len] = 0;
```

assuming you have allocated space for that.

Answer (score 4):

First off, C (and C++) is not dynamic like you know it from Java, C#, PHP and others. When you are presented with a string in C, the string is pretty much static in length.

To make the answer simpler, lets redefine your variables:

- `g->db_cmd` will be called `dest`,
- `l->db.param_value.val` will be called `src`, and
- `l->db.param_value.len` will be called `len`.

You should allocate a new string of size `len` plus one (for the extra null).

Allocate a new `dest`:

```
dest = calloc(sizeof(char), len + 1);
```

[calloc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html) allocates an array of chars as long as `len` plus one. After calloc() has allocated the array it fills it with nulls (or \0) thus you automatically will have a null appended to your `dest`string.

Next, copy the `src` to `dest` with [strncpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strncpy.html):

```
 strncpy(dest, src, len);
```

To convert this back to your variable names:

```
g->db_cmd = calloc(sizeof(char), l->db.param_value.len + 1);
strncpy(g->db_cmd, l->db.param_value.val, l->db.param_value.len);
```

Comment: In my opinion, `memcpy()` would be a more appropriate function to use than `strncpy()` in this example. Unless it's possible that the length of `l->db.param_value.val` is actually less than `l->db.param_value.len`.  In which case, that's a confusing set of data and/or member names.

Comment: Michael: you are absolutely right, given there is an Len variable. That would probably also shave of a few cycles when not checking for null in src. And Ken mentions elsewhere that he has to use memcpy(), so I should probably just change it!

Answer (score 3):

If you want string-copying semantics, why not use [a string-copying function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/narrow/strncpy)?

Comment: cant use it i need to use memcpy

Comment: @ken : *Why* though? If this is homework, then please tag your question as such.

Comment: Who says the source value is NUL terminated, esp. when it's a struct with a len attribute?

Comment: @pyroscope : Indeed, nobody said that. Vague questions sometimes yield incorrect answers -- that's just how it goes.

Comment: In this case it might be reasonable to assume the source and destination are null terminated (or should be) since another question by the OP using similar code uses `strlen()` all over the place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931193/concatenate-with-memcpy  However, maybe that's the problem the OP was having in that question...  I think the OP needs to figure out what the data they're dealing with is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are by default null-terminated.
If you want a to ad an extra NULL at the end you can write **"String\0"**
or `db_cmd[len]='\0'`

Comment: Strings may be null terminated or may not be. String *literals* are always null terminated. </pedantic>

Comment: @Billy : I thought C++ answerers were pedantic by default? ;-]

Answer (score 0):

If the source you're copying from also contains a NULL terminated string use

```
memcpy( g->db_cmd, l->db.param_value.val, l->db.param_value.len + 1 );
```

Otherwise you'll have to add the terminator yourself.

```
g->db_cmd[l->db.param_value.len] = '\0';
```

Of course, you need to ensure that the destination has enough room for this character.

Comment: Hey, good point the value i am copying does contain it but even with the +1 it does not append ??

Answer (score 0):

memcpy takes two pointers, and an integer.  In the lines that you say are crashing, you pass it a pointer, and two integers.  The code cannot dereference the second argument (0).
If you really really want to use memcpy, you have to have a pointer to a zero

```
char zero = 0;
memcpy(&g->db_cmd[l->db.param_value.len], &zero , 1);
```

But I would really suggest pyroscope's answer.  It's faster, and clearer.